# Error compiling Wizard Generated MFC App; missing CDocument declaration

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I consider myself pretty sharp with MFC, but I've ran into a problem lately that I have not been able to find a fix for online, nor have I been able to trace it down myself...

The problem is, some code I wrote back at the start of the year, has been placed on hold due to an iOS project that came up, so I had spend about 5 months to write that, and now I'm ready to go back to the last project, but it appears to have suffered from Code Rot.

The problem is, it's not Code Rot, there is actually a problem with my Build Env.  I'm using VS2008, for various reasons that shouldn't be the focus of the problem here anyways.

When I create a DEFAULT C++ MFC (Native) application, by simply creating the project, and then hitting FINISH on the wizard, then BUILD it, I get an error while the compiler is compiling the first CPP file.  It APPEARS to compile stdafx.cpp just fine, which is including all the AFX headers, but what ends up happening is I get an error that "CDocument" is undefined...  Now, I know enough MFC that this should just not be...

I've checked all my paths, and INCLUDE, LIB and so on, and they are all pointing to what is essentially

`c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE`

Along with some includes for the Windows SDK, and so on.  The error I'm getting is showing that AFXWIN.H IS coming from the ATLMFC\INCLUDE folder.

So, by this point, I have to assume maybe I have something else wrong?  Something updated some MFC DLL's, or LIB's, where they maybe should not have?

When I try to install from my VS2008 Team Foundation DVD (en_visual_studio_team_system_2008_team_suite_x86_x64wow_dvd_X##-####) either ISO or DVD, I just get an error when I attempt to launch the repair mode...

I'm not aware of any extended log files there might be to help track this down. (As to what the error is in the setup program while attempting to "repair" my VS2008 install, at least...)

I'm running on Win7, x86, with no UAC enabled.  Has anyone else had a problem like this?

Thanks guys.

Comment: the error is CDocument is undefined? In what file does it point to it being undefined?

Comment: In this case, it complains in my file "MFCTestDoc.h" where it's defined like so: "class CMFCTestDoc : public CDocument", which I do not see defined in afxwin.h, but it IS forward declared in afx.h as just "class CDocument;" down with the CArchive declaration...

Comment: Are you sure your include paths are correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, and it is so bad, I don't even want to answer this question, but I figure I better, because this could happen to someone else.

This whole problem occurred while I was editing a project that did not use MFC at all, but it was loaded into the WORKSPACE of a project that DID use MFC.  At one point, I did a "Find and Replace in Files", for Document to XmlDocument.  Well, little did I know, it would go out to my INCLUDE paths, and update the files there too.  So, my MFC "CDocument" got changed into "CXmlDocument" in the afxwin.h file.  (as well as afxwin.inl).  It took a lot of searching on my part to find this, because I was wisked off that project on to another about 6 months ago.  I come back to work on the ORIGINAL project that used MFC and waddaya know.  Code-Rot.  Well, since then a lot of changes happened to my PC, so I figured some new version of MFC got installed, or something.  So, I went searching the include path of VS2010 for CXmlDocument, which did not exist!  So, I figured, "Ok..  CXmlDocument is NOT a legit MFC Class."  So, I found where CDocument was declared, in VS2010, and matched it with what was in VS2008.  It was then I started to realize what had happened.  So, I replaced all instances of CXmlDocument with CDocument, and BAM!  Code compiles just fine...

So, the lesson for today Kids is if you do a search and replace in files, be DAMN CAREFUL what settings you use, and pay CLOSE attention to what files are modified!

I'm sorry to everyone to read this question and wasted any time reading it, however I do appreciate the attempts to help me on this.  Thank you guys/gals.